# How can I collect data in one fragment and show it in another fragment in android studio, I am using Shared Preferences to do this

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments

This is the function I made in one fragment to store my value,

```
  private fun nickdata(){
    

    val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val nicdat = binding.nickname.text.toString()
    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
    
    editor.putString("Nickname_key","trial")
    editor.apply()
    editor.commit()}
```

below is the code I am using to fetch data in another fragment

```
    val pref = activity!!.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val id = pref.getString("Nickname_Key", "trial")
    binding.nickdata.text = id
```

In output I am getting "trial" which is def value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it done

```
 private fun nickdata(){
    val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val nicdat = binding.nickname.text.toString()
    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()

    editor.putString("trial",nicdat)
    editor.apply()
    editor.commit()
```

this code in one fragment
below mentioned code where I want to fetch it

```
    val pref = activity!!.getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val nicdat = binding.nickdata.text.toString()
    val id = pref.getString("trial", nicdat)
    binding.nickdata.text = id
```

Comment: This is not the way you should answer, the same answer with just a few word changes. Please follow the code of conduct.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using the same shared preference in both fragments.

Also what you did is you stored the value trial not the value that you want to send the the other fragment.

```
val sharedPreferences = activity!!.getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val nicdat = binding.nickname.text.toString()
val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()

editor.putString("Nickname_key",nicdat)
editor.apply()
editor.commit()
```

For the other fragment

```
val pref = activity!!.getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val id = pref.getString("Nickname_Key", "trial")
binding.nickdata.text = id
```

Comment: `commit()` should not be called on the main thread. It's not needed at all unless you need to receive confirmation when the shared preference has been persisted to disk.

Comment: I used binding in the second fragment. It works now, Thanks for pointing out that I was not storing the right value

Answer (score 1):

You can use Fragment Result Listeners. More documentation: [Communicating between fragments.](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate) Here is some working code that controls navigation in my app:

In first fragment:

```
open fun navigate(idOfDestination: Int, bundle: Bundle?) {
    val tempBundle = bundle ?: Bundle()
    tempBundle.putInt(NAVIGATION_DESTINATION, idOfDestination)
    activity?.supportFragmentManager?.setFragmentResult(NAVIGATION_RESULT, tempBundle)
}
```

In target fragment, register the listener:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    activity?.supportFragmentManager?.setFragmentResultListener(NAVIGATION_RESULT, this, FragmentResultListener { _, bundle ->
        val destination = bundle.getInt(NAVIGATION_DESTINATION)
        bundle.remove(NAVIGATION_DESTINATION)
        navigationHandler(bundle,destination)
    })
}

private fun navigationHandler(bundle: Bundle?, idOfDestination: Int) {
    navController = Navigation.findNavController(binding.root)
    if (!FeatureControlManager.isDestinationAllowedToGo(idOfDestination)) {
        navController = childFragmentManager.fragments.first().findNavController()
    }
    navController.validateAndNavigate(navController, idOfDestination, childFragmentManager, bundle)
}
```